# How to export the same type in two different submodules with `pybind11`?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

In my C++ library I have two namespaces that share some symbol:

```
namespace NS1 {
  struct S1 { };
}

namespace NS2 { 
  using NS1::S1;

  struct S2 { };
}
```

I would like to export two submodule of my Python module with the same structure, *i.e.* having the submodule `NS1` export `S1`, and `NS2` export both `S1` and `S2`, with `S1` being the same type in both modules.

I tried this way:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m) {

  py::module_ m1 = m.def_submodule("NS1", "");
  py::module_ m2 = m.def_submodule("NS2", "");

  py::class_<NS1::S1>(m1, "S1");
  py::class_<NS2::S1>(m2, "S1");
  py::class_<NS2::S2>(m2, "S2");
}
```

But this does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test-python.py", line 3, in <module>
    from my_module import *
ImportError: generic_type: type "S1" is already registered!
```

How can I export the same type from two different submodules?